# How to easily fill a gas can at a modern gas pump?

Tags: gas, engine, motor, regulator, gasoline

I have 2.5 and 5 gallon gas cans that I use to fuel engines for various home improvement projects: lawn mower, weed whacker, chainsaw, electrical generator, post auger, pressure washer, etc.

I fill up these gasoline cans at the local gas station. The gas pumps are primarily designed for modern cars.

Trying to fill the gas cans on the ground, the gas pump **"clicks off"** every second or so. It's very difficult and annoying to fill the can. You need to squeeze the handle at the perfect amount of pressure, and even then the flow still often turns off.

[image: example picture of filling gas tanks]

My gas cans are newer plastic post-2009 EPA regulation cans. They have no vent and a permanent plastic filter after taking off the cap, which restricts the in-flow. This question also applies to filling metal jerry cans.

The station's pumps are likewise a modern pump design with safety features such as automatic cut-off for overflow or vapors. The pump's regulator cuts off gas unless in the perfect position, which seems to be only designed for new cars. The filler neck has a sleeve that requires pressure.

How can I fill a modern gas can at a modern gas station quickly and efficiently, without the gas pump clicking off every second?

Comment: I have yet to figure out a quick or efficient method, other then getting used to applying _just_ the right amount of pressure on the trigger. I have one that fills better than the others, but filling it then pouring into another can seems a bad idea, safety-wise.

Comment: Have had the same problem sometimes filling my pickup.  Too much of a squeeze and pump shuts off.  Remember the good old days when you drove over a rubber hose that went ding.

Comment: Move to New Jersey where pumping gas is someone else's problem. :)

Comment: This is not about Home Improvement.

Comment: Using a gas can to fill your chainsaw to reno your living room is Home something.

Comment: Invest in 10 Gallon gas can

Comment: i strip out all that annoying new safety stuff on the can neck, then it's easier.

Comment: This question is absolutely on topic for DIY: *"tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement tasks"*  ... *"maintenance of major appliances"* ... common tags [chainsaw](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainsaw), [lawn-mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower), [generator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generator)...

Comment: I used to get the clicking off, and in the end figured that if you do not put the nozzle fully into the jerry can, then you can full-press no probs. I generally have the spout about 1/3 way in. Of course you have to hold it steady, don't wanna let it slip out... I got into the habit of just holding it with both hands and it's no prob no more.

Comment: It shuts off because the back pressure of the air tricks the pump into thinking the can is full.   3 things u can do.   1) put gas in slower by not squeezing the handle all the way.  2) only insert the nozzle an inch or two into the can, allowing air to escape as it's displaced by gas. 3)  go to a different gas station...I've noticed some pumps are way more sensitive than others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've started bringing a funnel with me when filling up gas cans at the pump.

I use the funnel to jam the filler neck sleeve / retaining ring into the on position, as if it were inserted into a modern car.

Once the funnel is held in place correctly, you can [dispense a full stream of liquid gasoline](https://youtu.be/4xwsZ5vC5Oc?t=32) from the funnel tip. Put that into your gas can and it should fill up easily without clicking off or sensing an overflow.

Obviously, as with all things gasoline, be extremely careful decanting this flammable liquid.

[image: bring a funnel]

Answer (score 1):

I've never had this issue. I would suggest a different gas station and not putting the gas pump all the way into the can because it might be sensing (lack of) air flow?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem filling up gas cans, whether new plastic ones or old steel ones.

Note that the pump is designed to shut off if those little holes in the narrow end of the nozzle are covered by gas in the can.  This can happen fairly early in the fill cycle if you have the nozzle pushed all the way down into the can.  Just put the nozzle part way in, then raise it as the can fills.